# Error in getting the last element of array

Tags: javascript

I have to log the last element in an array. I try this code:

```
       $scope.t=["item1","item2","item3"];
       $scope.tablng= $scope.t.length ; 
       console.log( $scope.t[$scope.tablng]);
```

But i get `undefined`. How can i fix it please

Comment: Since there's nothing in array, last entry will be undefined. Did you expect something different?

Comment: see the updated post please :)

Answer (score 2):

In array, index are starting from 0, so you have to minus 1 to the length you retrieved to get the last element in array. A quick fix will be

```
$scope.t=["item1","item2","item3"];
$scope.tablng = $scope.t.length; 
console.log( $scope.t[$scope.tablng-1]);
```

An even better approach, is to also determine if the array is empty, because in that case `$scope.tablng` will be -1, which is again `undefined`

```
$scope.t=["item1","item2","item3"];
if ($scope.t.length > 0) {
   $scope.tablng = $scope.t.length-1; 
   console.log( $scope.t[$scope.tablng]); 
} else {
   // the array is empty
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56jyjjwt/1/

Comment: I would prefer `$scope.t[$scope.tablng - 1]` instead, respect to the property name `tablng`.

Comment: @SihemHcine My first approach use an empty array, so you will still see `undefined`, try to refresh and it should work now

Comment: @TrungDQ I agree and thanks for pointing that, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

You can write your prototype function:

```
Array.prototype.last=function(){
return this[this.length-1];
};

$scope.t=["item1","item2","item3"];
console.log($scope.t.last()); //"item3"
```

Answer (score 0):

when you get first item in array : array[0]

get last item in array: array[length-1]

In you code:

```
console.log( $scope.t[$scope.tablng-1]);
```